# Does Ansible manages all hosts in parallel or just five? (-f and :serial)

Tags: parallel-processing, ansible, fork

I read this two ansible docs:

[ansible-playbook -f --> Statement 1](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-f)

[ansible-playbook :serial --> Statement 2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)

and I found this two statements:

### Statement 1

```
-f <FORKS>, --forks <FORKS>
```

*specify number of parallel processes to use (default=5)*

### Statement 2

***Rolling Update Batch Size**. By default, Ansible will try to manage all of the machines referenced in a play in parallel. For a rolling update use case, you can define how many hosts Ansible should manage at a single time by using the serial keyword:*

### Question

What's correct? Does ansible uses all hosts at once or just 5?
Or is maybe 5 just the default value of the `-f` parameter?

Thanks for clarifying that!

Cheers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`--forks` sets *number of hosts* on which the current **task** is executed simultaneously (see [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-forks))

`serial` sets *number (or percentage/fraction) of hosts* on which the **playbook** is run first, and after succesful completion, it is applied on another *number of hosts* (see [Delegation, Rolling Updates, and Local Actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html))

#### Example:

With settings:

- Inventory with `host[1-7]`
- Playbook with task1 and task2
- `--fork 2`
- `serial: 3`

The procedure is:

1. run `task1` on `host1` and `host2`
2. run `task1` on `host3`
3. run `task2` on `host1` and `host2`
4. run `task2` on `host3`
5. finish playbook run on `host[1-3]`
6. run `task1` on `host4` and `host5`
7. run `task1` on `host6`
8. run `task2` on `host4` and `host5`
9. run `task2` on `host6`
10. finish playbook run on `host[4-6]`
11. run `task1` on `host7`
12. run `task2` on `host7`
13. finish playbook run on `host7`

Because:

- you are executing one task on 2 hosts at a time at most (`--fork`)
- you are executing whole playbook on 3 hosts at a time at most (`serial`)

Comment: This is an excellent description that I had to look all over for.  Question though, how does the flow change if one adds "strategy: free"?

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this doc (Ansible Performance Tuning)](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-performance-tuning) should provide all the detail you require. However in summary, `--forks` broadly configures the amount of parallel processes that Ansible can spawn, and therefore the maximum number of hosts that can be configured in parallel. The value of `--fork` defaults to 5.

If however, `serial` is set to a lower figure than is in effect via the `--forks` parameter, then this is the number of hosts that will be targeted in parallel *for the task or play on which the `serial` parameter is set*.

The combination is useful as it allows you to tune your playbook to run against the best number of hosts for performance, but then limit certain tasks to a fraction of that value (for example to ensure that a service restart is staggered rather than applied to all hosts at the same time, thus ensuring no downtime on that service from the POV of end users).